# build.gradle dependency on gitlab (local server)

Tags: java, git, gradle, gitlab

Note: I am not very familiar with gradle

Several projects I've worked on with gradle have a dependencies section such as the following where I used the Sugar ORM:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
}
```

I can compile the Sugar ORM project using:

```
'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
```

I have a local server hosting a small library on GitLab which I want to include in my next gradle project.

I want to be able to do the following in my dependencies section for my new project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'git.devstuff.com:?:?'
}
```

http://git.devstuff.com/admin/broadcast_lib.git (local server) is the where my git project is, but I don't know how to fill in the question marks in the above code snippet.

The end result I would like is to include the library in a future project via the following in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'git.devstuff.com:broadcast_lib:1.0'
}
```

I'll update the question if I'm lacking information.